# schedule job interviews between candidates

Tags: calendar, job-scheduler

I want to send the same link to multiple persons in order to schedule job interviews with them.
Example:

- Let's say I want to interview one person every Wednesday at 13:00pm.
- I have 10 applicants
- I want to send the same link to the 10 applicants
- The applicants should just click on the time slot of their choosing
- I'll get a notification about their name and choice

Answer (score 0):

Already found an online solution:

https://youcanbook.me/

does the trick